How is the controlled-n NOT gate represented in Qiskit?

I want to decompose an 8-control qubit gate like the one in the picture on the right using Qiskit, similar to the decomposition shown. To do this, I need a C7XGate for 7 control bits, but it seems that Qiskit only supports up to a C4XGate. What should I do?

For multi-controlled X gate, use Qiskit's class MCXGate which can be added to your circuit as follows:
circ.mcx(range(7), 7)


I got it! Thank you sir
